# Laravel Timestamps Update error about id

Tags: laravel, timestamp

Hi I am new to laravel and I'm now trying to do the authentication of my application.
The problem now I have when I tried to active my account by email check is that it says:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2014-07-23 16:51:55, `code` = , `active` = 1 where `id` is null)

In my database I have a column named "idUser". How can I change the default column "id" into "idUser"?

Here is my code in controller.

```
/*
Email Activation
*/
public function getActivate($code){
     $user=User::where('code','=',$code)->where('active','=',0);
     if($user->count()){

        $user = $user->first();
        //Update user to active state
        $user->active   =1;
        $user->code     ='';
        if($user->save()){
           return Redirect::route('home')
           ->with('flash_message','Activated! You can now sign in!');
        }

     }
    return Redirect::route('home')
        ->with('flash_message','Could not activate your account.Please try again later. ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage

```
// Model
protected $primaryKey = 'whateverColumnYouHave';
```

Answer (score 0):

set $primaryKey in your User model to idUser:

protected $primaryKey = 'idUser';

Note: Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a primaryKey property to override this convention. Likewise, you may define a connection property to override the name of the database connection that should be used when utilizing the model.

source: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

Open your model and add this protected variable. This will overwrite the existing.

protected $primaryKey = 'idUser'; //this will change the default primary key.

ex:

**app/models/user.php**

```
class User extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'userlists'; //This will change your default table

    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; //This will change the default primary key.

    protected $hidden = array('password'); 

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

}
```